# Zend Framework 2 instaliation without console or composer?

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

My development server has all these and I created application everything working.

And now I need to upload my app to production server but copying with ftp client doesn't work like with zf1. Is there a way to make it work without console.

I would have tried with `exec()` from php but that doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

how to upload production ready app to server where you don't have any way to open console or run composer? maybe composer has something for this?

Comment: are you getting any partiular error?

Comment: I dont know what was wrong but now working fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a console. Copying the files will work without a problem. If it doesn't, there's files that you have missed. PHP Apps are that simple, check error logs for when something doesn't work right.

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to use Composer to install it on your local machine first, and then upload the project as-is to the web server, and it will 'just work'.

Using composer locally will make sure your autoloading etc is nicely setup, so when you upload via FTP everything works perfectly.